# Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock - How to get index of Buy and Sell days

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm

I was able to find solution "Find value of max profit".

```
  const pricesEachDay = [1,2,5,8,7,1,2,3]

  const mainFunction = (pricesEachDay) => {
  let buyPrice = pricesEachDay[0];
  let bestProfit = 0;

  for (const price of pricesEachDay) {
    const currentProfit = price - buyPrice;
    buyPrice = Math.min(buyPrice, price);
    bestProfit = Math.max(bestProfit, price - buyPrice);
  }

  return bestProfit;
}
```

My Question is. How would i approach it, if i wanted to find indexes of both day i bought stock and day i sell and return it along with max profit. So i can highlight it in React.
Thank you!

Comment: should be "buyPrice" sorry about a typo. it's corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in local variables.

```js
const pricesEachDay = [1,2,5,8,7,1,2,3]

const mainFunction = (pricesEachDay) => {
  let buyPrice = pricesEachDay[0];
  let bestProfit = 0;
  let boughtDay = 1;
  let lastPriceDay = 1;
  let soldDay = 1;
  let idx = 1;
  for (const price of pricesEachDay) {
    if(price < buyPrice) {
        buyPrice = price;
        lastPriceDay = idx;
    } 
    if(price - buyPrice > bestProfit) {
        bestProfit = price - buyPrice
        soldDay = idx;
        boughtDay = lastPriceDay;
    }
    idx++;
  }
  return [bestProfit, boughtDay, soldDay];
}

let arr = mainFunction(pricesEachDay)
console.log("Maximum profit: " + arr[0])
console.log("Day stock was bought: " + arr[1])
console.log("Day stock was sold: " + arr[2])
```

Output:

```
Maximum profit: 7
Day stock was bought: 1
Day stock was sold: 4
```